# How to find the last occurrence of a set of characters from a string

Tags: c#, string, lastindexof

I'm trying to find the last operator (`+`, `-`, `*` or `/`) in a string.

I was trying to use the method `string.indexof('operator', i);`, but in this case I could only get the single type of `operator`. Is there any better solution for this?

The value of `string` could, for example, be:

`1+1/2*3-4`

or

`1/2-3+4*7`

It means the last operator could be any of them.

Comment: +1, good question. I know how to do this, but it wouldn't be elegant, so until I work out a way this could be done concisely (using something like LINQ) I'll wait to see other suggestions. EDIT: Sorted, there's a method for this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.lastindexofany.aspx

The `LastIndexOfAny` method is what you're after. It will take an array of characters, and find the last occurrence of any of the characters.

```
var myString = "1/2-3+4*7";
var lastOperatorIndex = myString.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { '+', '-', '/', '*' });
```

In this scenario, `lastOperatorIndex == 7`

If you're wanting to store the char itself to a variable you *could* have:

```
var myString = "1/2-3+4*7";
var operatorChar = myString[myString.LastIndexOfAny(new char[] { '+', '-', '/', '*' })];
```